# badges based on tag questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, badges

I believe there should be tag badges for questions as well as answers.

While it is true that SX sites are, in the bottom line, about answers, there are still badges for asking questions with many votes or many views. I believe there should be question-based tag-specific badges: In my opinion, users asking many good questions in a certain tag contribute to the "development" of the tag on the site, and this merits recognition.